How to Calculate the Stopping Distance of Train on a Complex Track
I am attempting to determine when a train should begin braking to reach a certain point at a complete stop. There are several factors that need to be considered that make this more complicated and I have been unable to find a solution. The factors are as follows:

The train's ability to brake is a function of velocity. In this case the train has more braking potential the slower it is going. This is modelled as an exponential decay with a constant force below a certain speed.

Example of the speed force curve of a train braking system

2. The track is not even and has various grades over the length between the train and the stopping distance. The grades are modeled as having a start point, end point and constant grade between those points.

The mass of the train is known and considered to be constant, I am using the value 9,000,000 kg but am looking for a general solution.
The trains initial velocity is also known, I have been using 16m/s
I have been able to solve it not considering the grades by using an integral
$s=\int_{0}^{V_{i}} \frac{v}{\frac{f(v)}{m}}\mathrm{d}v$
Where f(x) is the force s a function of velocity. However I can't figure out how I would factor in the grades as they seem to need to be expressed as a function of distance and I can't formulate any equation that allows me to account for them. I am open to iterative solutions as this will eventually be put into a program which focuses on simulating the movement of rail vehicles in general, but I'm pretty much at the limit of my ability at this point. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Anyone looking for example values the ones I am using are as follows:
Initial Velocity: 16m/s
Train Mass: 900,000kg
Distance to Stop Point: 800m
Grade 1: 600m-700m, -0.1%
Grade 2: 700m-800m, -0.15%
f(v)= $500000e^{-0.03(v-3))} $ Newtons

Your force is a function of the distance x , not of the velocity?

My mistake, I forgot to change the x to v when I was putting the equation together. It is meant to be a function of velocity. I have updated the question.

I don’t think that the  brake force is a function of the train velocity

It is when using dynamic braking on a Diesel Electric locomotive. The maximum braking force achievable is limited by the speed of the train.

I think you can solve this working backwards in time; assume that the train has stopped at the correct location, and then integrate backwards in time (or alternatively, model the braking force as an acceleration force). The total force on the train is then the braking force + the force of gravity, which depends on the current location of the train.
When the accelerating train reaches the initial velocity, its current location will be the point where it must start braking.
You can probably solve the problem analytically if you can break the track into piecewise linear portions, as you have done in the problem statement. Otherwise, a numerical solution using this approach should be possible. If you want, I can try to elaborate further or write a simple Python implementation (when I find the time)
Edit: I couldn't help myself, and wrote Python script that I think solves the problem given the parameters listed in the bottom of your post. The answer is that the train should start braking when it reaches $x \approx 502$ meters, i.e. 298 meters before it needs to stop. I have assumed that the grades you list are all downhill (since they are negative). The time $t=0$ is defined as the time when the train starts braking. Below are some plots.
!


Edit 2: And here is the script, with some comments
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

v0 = 16  # initial speed of train, m/s
m = 9 * 1e5  # mass of train [kg]
g = 9.81  # gravitational acceleration [m /s^2]
F0 = 5 * 1e5  # max breaking force of the train [N]
gamma = 0.03  # exponential decay rate of braking force [s / m]
velocity_cutoff = 3  # velocity below which train brakes at max force [m/s]
dt = 0.001  # time difference used for numerical integration [s]


def slope_in_percent(x):
    """ Returns the slope of the track at a given position x.
        x = 0 corresponds to the stopping position of the train.
    """
    if 0 <= x <= 100:
        return -0.15
    elif 100 < x <= 200:
        return -0.1
    else:
        return 0


def get_gravitatonal_force(x):
    """calculates the gravitational force at a point x
       from the slope and the mass of the train.
    """
    slope = slope_in_percent(x)
    angle = np.arctan(slope / 100)
    F = m * g * np.sin(angle)
    return F


def get_braking_force(v):
    """
    Braking force of the train, function of the velocity v
    """
    if v > velocity_cutoff:
        F = F0 * np.exp(-gamma * (v - 3))
    else:
        F = F0
    return F


def get_force(x, v):
    return get_braking_force(v) + get_gravitatonal_force(x)


# initial configuration; train is still at stopping location
x = 0
v = 0
t = 0
F = get_force(x, v)
slope = slope_in_percent(x)

# define lists for saving data
x_list = [x]
v_list = [v]
t_list = [t]
F_list = [F]
slope_list = [slope]

# integrate motion backwards in time until we reach final velocity
while v < v0:
    F = get_force(x, v)
    dv = F * dt / m
    x = x + (v + dv / 2) * dt
    v = v + dv
    t = t + dt

    slope = slope_in_percent(x)

    x_list.append(x)
    v_list.append(v)
    t_list.append(t)
    F_list.append(F)
    slope_list.append(slope)

print(x)  # distance from the stopping point at which the train must start braking.


Looks like a good solution. Appreciate the effort of writing the python code. Should work well, and also will allow me to adjust it to a multibody simulation of the train as my simulation gets more mature.
